# Highcharts bar chart, bar is getting display below the x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

In [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) library we are using bar chart and sometimes value bars are getting displayed below the x-axis label and over the legends.

This issue does not continue generating.

```
Jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/4r21uwzL/
```

Please have a look below image of the issue.

[image]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Jsfiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4r21uwzL/   This issue does not continue generating.

Comment: Hi @Maulik sojitra, Your live example does not show the issue, could you change it? Which Highcharts version do you use?

Comment: Currently, I am using 7.0.2 version and as I have already said this issue does not continuously generate so it will not be reproducing in jsfiddle demo.

Comment: @Maulik sojitra, Is this problem also present in the latest version of Highcharts? If not, it was a bug and it was fixed.

Comment: @ppotaczek I haven't checked with the older version. Currently, I am using 7.0.2 version, I will check with the latest version 7.1.1 and update you.

Comment: Hi @Maulik sojitra, Any updates?